# android all edittext width changes on orientation change and on focus

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, android-orientation

help! i have a set of edittext fields in a (LinearLayout) which i enable and disable programatically.
there is no problem with the edittexts widths when i enable and disable the fields [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpv2y.png). the problem comes after the edittexts are enabled and either

1. the orientation changes or
2. [user clicks to focus on any of the edittexts then the widths of **ALL the edittexts** become 1 character.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1zof.png)

here is the code for one of my editexts. the rest are the same, only id is different.

```
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/purchase_price"
                android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionNext"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal">
```

here is the code to enable a field.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    enabledEdittext = mPurchasePrice.getBackground();
    disabledEditext = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.disabled_edittext);
    .
    .
    .
    mPurchasePrice.setBackground(enabledEdittext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use EditText.setFocusable(false) to disable editing
EditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true) to enable editing;

instead of changing the background.

Comment: I changed the background because the client's requirement was to remove the line under the edittext when the field is disabled.